# Line between the tree node property

Tags: c#, wpf, tree

C#, WPF, Windows 7, PC, Visaul Studio 2010

Application Easytask

I have made an application with a tree and a treeview whee the user can add and remove 
nodes on the fly.

However my nodes does not get a line between the different nodes in the tree which is visiable 
in almost all examples of Treeview on the internet.

Which property do I have to set so I a parent nodes draw a line from itself to it's parentnode ?

Regards Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been asked:
[Lines between nodes in WPF TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603493/lines-between-nodes-in-wpf-treeview)

Small google search found:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/30cb182c-9419-40bd-946e-87971515fb95

Comment: Thanks
Hehe, that a lot of code for such simple thing, perhaps it is easier just to directly draw lines between the nodes.

Comment: That's basically what he's doing in his control template.  He declares a path that draws the lines between the nodes.